# Whenever I export my model to fbx and import it back to blender, it gets messed up

Tags: export, import

I have this very simple model which consists of 2 elongated cubes and some bones. As the title says, whenever I export it and import it back into blender, it gets messed up.

here's the model before and after
[image: Model before and after]

these are my export settings

[image: export settings]

and these are my import settings

[image: imports settings]

I hope I have provided enough information

Please and thank you

Edit: Someone told me to upload the model itself so here it is:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with importitng and exporting FBX files, but I see that your export settings panel has the "!EXPERIMENTAL! Apply Transform" option checked whereas the import one does not. Might that be the reason?

Comment: @JohnEason Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it did not work, sorry

Comment: Maybe [upload](https://blend-exchange.com/help) your Blend file in that case so that someone else can have a look.

Comment: @JohnEason Ok I will, Thanks